# Can I split this integral to a sum over three contours?

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, contour-integration, gauge-theory

I have the following integral

$$ Z = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int dx \, \frac{1}{(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)}\times \frac{1}{(x+\epsilon - a_1)(x + \epsilon - a_2)(x+ \epsilon - a_3)} $$

and this integral has poles at $x=a_1,a_2,a_3$ from the first factor and so on for the second one $x=a_i - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is just a number. I want to evaluate this integral around $a_1,a_2,a_3$ by taking small contours around these points or shifting them into the complex plane (i.e. by a small deformation like $a_i \to a_i + 0i $). This is motivated from instanton partition functions in physics. So are there any tips or guidelines on how to "nicely" do this?

Comment: I presume that the $a_i$ are distinct and that $\epsilon$ is small enough that the integrand has a total of $6$ distinct poles? Also, you are evaluating the integral over a simple contour that bounds all of the poles in its interior?

Comment: @MPW Yes, as you say, I also see 6 poles and indeed ϵϵ is small. And yes, as you say about the contour (which I don't know how to draw here) but it should be something like a rectangle that passes from all the poles. Also, and I am confused with that, if I change the poles by adding 0i0i then I think only half of them will contribute to the integration since 3 of them will fall out of the "rectangle" (the contour I mean).